# Java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError, getting this error launching url's on xampp tomcat server

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, xampp

I am getting this error when accessing the URL of a servlet java class file which I placed in XAMPP tomcat.
The error is as follows
[image]

These are my JDK and JRE folders
[image]

I was thinking maybe there is something wrong with the versions of JDK or JRE versions I installed.
If i missed out any important imformation, I am happy to provide it

Comment: Does this answer your question? [tomcat UnsupportedClassVersionError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30257044/tomcat-unsupportedclassversionerror)

Comment: Pick one or the other - you compiled with 15 but are running with 8.